# Code generated properties in AutoMapper mappings

Tags: c#-4.0, automapper

I have an Entity called **Artist** that looks like this:

```
public class Artist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public string UrlFriendly { get; set; }
}
```

And my Artist View Model looks exactly the same, except it is named `ArtistVM`.

Notice the `UrlFriendly` property. I want this property to be generated through code. I would like all letters with accents ... etc to be replaced with their English equivalent and also to be turned into lower case.

For example the name **Édith Piaf** would become `edith-piaf`.

Ignoring Automapper and the accented letters, I know how to do the rest like so:

```
artist.FName.ToLower() + "-" + artist.LName.ToLower();
```

But is there a way I can configure AutoMapper Mappings to do this for the `UrlFriendly` property when mapping from `ArtistVM` to `Artist`?

Comment: Is your UrlFriendly property something that exists in the DB?

Comment: Yep, it is a field in the database.

Comment: So what's the problem? Don't you just map it straight from the DB then? I'm confused as to why you would need any logic in C#?

Comment: It ought to exist in the Db, there is a column in the Artist databse to store it. But the value needs to be computed from `FName` and `LName`

Comment: It ought to but it doesn't? Just curious why the source type has that property.

Comment: The reason the `UrlFriendly` property exists on `Artist.cs` is because it is  used in my MVC route